# How can I find the Radius of convergence of this power series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

let the power series $ \sum{a_n x^n}$ where ${(a_n)}_n$ is defined as:

$a_{3n}=\frac{1}{5^n}, a_{3n+1}=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}, a_{3n+2}=2^{3 n}, \quad n \in N $

I figured out that I should try to calculate both $Lim \frac{a_{3n+1}}{a_{3n}}$ and $Lim \frac{a_{3n+2}}{a_{3n+1}}$ and take the max of them, is this correct ?

Comment: Might be easier to use the root test.

Comment: You are allowed to split the series into the 3 obvious parts, if at the end it turns out that all 3 parts are absolutely convergent. Then you get 2 geometric series and one that is asymptotically equivalent to a geometric series.

Comment: @martycohen how exactly ?

Comment: @LutzLehmann the third one is divergent, should I conclude that it diverges ?

Comment: Please provide proof. $\sum(8x^3)^k$ has a non-zero radius of convergence.

Comment: It is a known fact that the radius of convergence of a power series is $1/R$ were $R=\limsup_n\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $R$ be the radius of convergence of the power series. It is well-known
that $R$ can be computed by the following Cauchy-Hadamard formula:

$$
\frac{1}{R}=\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}|a_{n}|^{\frac{1}{n}},
$$
with the convention that $\frac{1}{0}=+\infty$ and $\frac{1}{+\infty}=0$.

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. If $n=3k$ for some $k$, then
\begin{eqnarray*}
|a_{n}|^{\frac{1}{n}} & = & \left(\frac{1}{5^{k}}\right)^{\frac{1}{3k}}\\
 & = & 5^{-\frac{1}{3}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence, $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}|a_{3k}|^{\frac{1}{3k}}=5^{-\frac{1}{3}}$.

If $n=3k+1$ for some $k$, then
\begin{eqnarray*}
|a_{n}|^{\frac{1}{n}} & = & \left\{ \left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)^{k^{2}}\right\} ^{\frac{1}{3k+1}}\\
 & = & \left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)^{\frac{k^{2}}{3k+1}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Note that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}|a_{3k+1}|^{\frac{1}{3k+1}} & = & \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\left[\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)^{k}\right]^{\frac{k}{3k+1}}\\
 & = & \left[e^{-1}\right]^{\frac{1}{3}}\\
 & = & e^{-\frac{1}{3}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
In the above, we invoked the fact that $(1-\frac{1}{k})^{k}\rightarrow e^{-1}$
and the continuity of the function $(x,y)\mapsto x^{y}$ at the point
$(e^{-1},\frac{1}{3})$.

If $n=3k+2$ for some $k$, then
\begin{eqnarray*}
|a_{n}|^{\frac{1}{n}} & = & \left(2^{3k}\right)^{\frac{1}{3k+2}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Clearly $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}|a_{3k+2}|^{\frac{1}{3k+2}}=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}2^{\frac{3k}{3k+2}}=2$.

Note that $5^{-\frac{1}{3}}<e^{-\frac{1}{3}}<2$. We go to show that
$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}|a_{n}|^{\frac{1}{n}}=2$. Let $\varepsilon>0$
be arbitrary. Without loss of genearlity (by replacing $\varepsilon$
with a smaller value), we may assume that $(5^{-\frac{1}{3}}-\varepsilon,5^{-\frac{1}{3}}+\varepsilon)$,
$(e^{-\frac{1}{3}}-\varepsilon,e^{-\frac{1}{3}}+\varepsilon)$, and
$(2-\varepsilon,2+\varepsilon)$ are pairwisely disjoint. Denote $b_{n}=|a_{n}|^{\frac{1}{n}}$.
Choose $K_{1},K_{2},K_{3}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $b_{3k}\in(5^{-\frac{1}{3}}-\varepsilon,5^{-\frac{1}{3}}+\varepsilon)$
whenever $k\geq K_{1}$, $b_{3k+1}\in(e^{-\frac{1}{3}}-\varepsilon,e^{-\frac{1}{3}}+\varepsilon)$
whenever $k\geq K_{2}$, and $b_{3k+2}\in(2-\varepsilon,2+\varepsilon)$
whenever $k\geq K_{3}$. Let $K=\max(K_{1},K_{2},K_{3})$. Then, for
any $n\geq3K$, we have $b_{n}<2+\varepsilon$. (For, if $n=3k$ for
some $k$, then $k\geq K$. Therefore, $b_{n}=b_{3k}<5^{-\frac{1}{3}}+\varepsilon<2+\varepsilon$.
We can argue similarly if $n=3k+1$ and $n=3k+2$.) Therefore, $\sup_{n\geq3K}b_{n}\leq2+\varepsilon$
and hence $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_{n}\leq2+\varepsilon$. Since
$\varepsilon>0$ is arbitrary, we have that $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_{n}\leq2$.
On the other hand, since $(b_{3n+2})$ is a subsequence of $(b_{n})$
that converges to $2$, we have that $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_{n}\geq\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_{3n+2}=2$.
That is, $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_{n}=2$.

Hence, the radius of convergence $R$ is given by $R=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Yep. Exactly what I meant in my commet.

Comment: Thank you for elaboration, given that we have 3 different series with 3 different radius of convergence, couldn't we just choose the smallest one to ensure we have convergence for all of them ?

Comment: No. The limits of three subsequence just help us to determine $\limsup_n |a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}$.

Comment: We cannot jump to conclusion immediately.